# Angular 6 Reactive Form - how to set conditional value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use Angular 6 and Reactive Form in my project. I have a question about how to set a condition, for example if the data is empty then don't convert to date, leave it empty.

```
this.editForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        firstName: [this.user.firstName, Validators.required],
        lastName: [this.user.lastName, Validators.required],        
        workingDate: [
            moment(this.user.workingDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
          Validators.required
        ], ....
       }
```

I want to put a conditional like if the this.user.workingDate == "" then leave it empty (if we use moment(), it will display the current date instead)

how to do that ?

Comment: Using terinary(?) operator, you can set the condition

Comment: thank you i just know that we can use tertinary operators inside array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
workingDate: [
          this.user.workingDate ? moment(this.user.workingDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY") : null,
          Validators.required
        ], ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the terinary operator, you can set the condition like below

```
workingDate: [
   (this.user.workingDate ? moment(this.user.workingDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY") : ''), Validators.required
]
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkvhea)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.editForm = this.fb.group(
  { workingDate: [this.user.workingDate ? moment(this.user.workingDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY") : null, Validators.required],
    mobileNo: [this.user.mobileNo ? this.user.mobileNo : null, [Validators.maxLength(11), Validators.minLength(10)]]
   }
```

> import * as moment from 'moment'